# Can someone please explain the joke in this picture?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, soft-question

I came across the following picture:

[image]

I tried to do some research online to figure out why this picture was funny - but I couldn't really figure it out. Am I missing something, can someone please tell me what the intended joke in this picture is supposed to be?

Thanks!

Comment: The math is entirely made up, and has no relation to reality.

Comment: I don't think this is supposed to be funny (and the expression is most likely nonsense writer cooked up as a plot device.) Apparently it is [Doctor Sivana from DC Comics](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/forums/gen-discussion-1/five-more-things-you-most-likely-dont-know-about-y-2011012/)

Comment: If it is meant as to make fun of the ideas in modern theoretical physics (in particular astronomy) , it is a good parody, but most people won't understand the message and rather believe that the strange ideas must be correct (why should they be used otherwise ?). It isn't a funny comic since it reflects the deep crises of theoretical physics.

Comment: Thanks everyone!